# IIS Crashes when querying Style attribute of Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am encounterig the following issue when loading an UpdatePanel in a WebForms ASP.NET application.

I have the following piece of HTML ...

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updImgPreview" class="col-5" ClientIDMode="static" UpdateMode="conditional" OnLoad="updImgPreview_OnLoad">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlImagePreview" CssClass="mt-5" ClientIDMode="static" Visible="false">

                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFXPreview" ClientIDMode="static" Style="border:1px solid #606060;" CssClass="mb-5 background-fit"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlWINPreview" ClientIDMode="static" Style="border:1px solid #606060;" CssClass="mb-5 background-fit"></asp:Panel>

            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It's being updated using the javascript call ...

```
    __doPostBack("updImgPreview", "");
```

The following code behind is being executed when an ASP:UpdatePanel is being "loaded" (via OnLoad event handler). It works the first time the request is made but crashes IIS [Express] on subsequent requests. The CPU % for IIS Express spikes and stays there indefinitely.

```
this.pnlFXPreview.Style.Remove("background-image");
```

Stepping through it in the debugger reveals no exceptions being thrown. It merely returns control directly back to the browser without stepping through any more code, yet leaving IIS [Express] in a hung state. I have placed a "watch" on the pnlFXReview reference and when I attempt to expand its Style property I receive the following error.

> "To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function
>   'System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection.Count.get" all threads were allowed
>   to run. This may have changed the state of the process and any
>   breakpoints encountered have been skipped."

I am at a 100% loss for how to approach this. Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you comment this line ?

Comment: It processes fine, but obviously I don't get my background set that way ... the problem seems to revolve specifically, around the CssStyleCollection referenced by the property(??). I can enumerate other properties (e.g. Attributes) with no problem. It's just the Style property.

Comment: Is the `Remove` method the issue ? if you access another property like `Count`does it work ?

Comment: The Add function causes the same problem. When I expand the Style property of the control in the Watch list in Visual Studio ... i get the error mentioned in the OP as well. It appears to be ANY attempt to access the Style property causes this issue.

Comment: Does the same happen in a minimal project containing only this code and a single page?

Comment: As I don't know what is contributing to the problem I am not sure what to add and what to leave out. The page is very busy and has lots of moving pieces. As it works the first time I submit the request, but fails only on a second  ... following an UpdatePanel refresh plus some interactions with a web service and Session state ... it's a bit hard to narrow down. I have in the meantime, arrived at a work-around which resolves my problem ... but does not technically answer the question. I replaced the problem code with ... `((PanelStyle)this.pnlWINPreview.ControlStyle).BackImageUrl = "" `